# Cache git credential manager web login

Tags: git, git-credential-manager

I am using latest git with git credential manager. I am **authenticating by web login** to my user account (our organisation uses single sign on, so it is only a click). However, I have to do this "click" each time I push or pull something. Git credential helper is already configured to the credential manager.

I am looking for a feature like the `credential.helper cache` command which (on default) would cache authentication information for 15 minutes, so that -- after using the web login authentication once -- I dont have to do it again for 15 minutes. I could not find it in the documentation (neither of git and the credential.helper feature nor in the git credential manager pages). What am I missing?